# how to fix text direction in itextsharp or itext7 for arabic text in .net core

Tags: .net, asp.net-core

I want to generate a pdf from SQL server database  which contains Arabic data or Pashto data, I can read the data but the problem is that, that the text is shown in reverser mode with a single letter, for example: the real data is رحمن الله but in pdf it is shown as ه ل ل ا ن م ح ر .

I tried Base Direction

Comment: There's an example involving Arabic in the section entitled [Internationalization](https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/ebooks/itext-7-converting-html-to-pdf-with-pdfhtml/chapter-6-using-fonts-in-pdfhtml#Chapter6:UsingfontsinpdfHTML-Internationalization) which may give you some help.